# wget does not set cookies

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, wget

Could someone tell me why my command does not work?

Here is my form:

```
<form id="query" method="POST" action="https://weblogin.mycompany.com/"
enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" autocomplete="off">
<table border="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td class="fieldname">Username:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="user" size="20" value="" class="inputfield" /> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="fieldname">Password:</td>
<td><input type="password" name="pass" class="inputfield" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="fieldname"></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Log in &raquo;" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<div id='notifyuser'></div>
</form>
```

And here is my wget command:

% wget --save-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt --post-data 'user=my_id&pass=my_passwd' \ https://weblogin.mycompany.com/

After I executed the wget command above, the cookie file is empty.

```
% cat /tmp/cookies.txt
# HTTP cookie file.
# Generated by Wget on 2013-07-02 16:23:39.
# Edit at your own risk.
```

And the http response:

```
% wget --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies /tmp/wget03_cookies.txt --post-data 'user=my_id&pass=my_passwd' **https://weblogin.mycompany.com/**
 --2013-07-03 09:52:06--  https://weblogin.mycompany.com/
 Resolving weblogin.mycompany.com... 1.1.1.1
 Connecting to weblogin.mycompany.com|1.1.1.1|:443... connected.
 HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
 Length: 4477 (4.4K) [text/html]
 Saving to: `index.html.10'

 100%[===========================================================================>] 4,477       --.-K/s   in 0s

 2013-07-03 09:52:06 (36.8 MB/s) - `index.html.10' saved [4477/4477]
```

What did I do wrong?

---

I might find a solution at this thread: [wget with authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272770/wget-with-authentication)

The solution is like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

# get the login page to get the hidden field data
wget -a log.txt -O loginpage.html http://foobar/default.aspx
hiddendata=`grep value < loginpage.html | grep foobarhidden | tr '=' ' ' | awk '{print $9}' | sed s/\"//g`
rm loginpage.html

# login into the page and save the cookies
postData=user=fakeuser'&'pw=password'&'foobarhidden=${hiddendata}
wget -a log.txt -O /dev/null --post-data ${postData} --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies cookies.txt http://foobar/default.aspx

# get the page your after
wget -a log.txt -O results.html --load-cookies cookies.txt http://foobar/lister.aspx?id=42
rm cookies.txt
```

What I don't understand is --
What am I supposed to use to substitute 'foobarhidden' while generating hiddendata?

I believe the following portion should give me the answer. But I dont know what exactly to do:

```
% grep value < loginpage.html | grep hidden
3:109:<input type=hidden name=pubcookie_g_req value="b25lPWFsb2hhLmFrYW1haS5jb20mdHdvPWFsb2hhJnRocmVlPTEmZm91cj1hNWEmZml2ZT1HRVQmc2l4PWFsb2hhLmFrYW1haS5jb20mc2V2ZW49THc9PSZlaWdodD0mYWthX2ZyYWc9Jmhvc3RuYW1lPWFsb2hhLmFrYW1haS5jb20mbmluZT0xJmZpbGU9JnJlZmVyZXI9KG51bGwpJnNlc3NfcmU9MCZwcmVfc2Vzc190b2s9NjMzMzQ0OTI3JmZsYWc9MA==">
4:110:<input type=hidden name=post_stuff value="">
5:111:<input type=hidden name=relay_url value="https://weblogin.mycompany.com/PubCookie.reply">
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What was in the HTTP response that came back from the server?  Perhaps there was an error returned?

Comment: BTW, my wget's version is 1.12.

Comment: Thank you, @RichieHindle I'll post the response in 'answer' area, because it's too long to put here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you say you're connecting to `https://...` but in your log it's `http://...` - perhaps that's the problem?  Make sure you're using `https://...` on the command line.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that, @RichieHindle ! I retried it with https and the results are the same. Again, the message will be posted in answer area. In addition, the page 'weblogin.mycompany.com' has lots of javascript codes in it. Would this cause wget stop working? Thanks again!

Comment: @CharlieYen: You should edit the new information into the question, rather than posting it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you for telling me that, @RichieHindle. Still kind of new to this forum. And so sorry for not following the rules. I am going to delete the new info in the answering area and update the original post. Thanks again.

Comment: @CharlieYen: What is in the file `index.html.10` - perhaps an error message?

Comment: To answer your question, @RichieHindle. The file index.html.10 is the actual login page with an error message saying: Your session has expired. Please re-login. Thanks.

Comment: @CharlieYen: I'm sorry, I'm out of ideas. :-(

Comment: I still appreciate your help a lot, @RichieHindle! In addition, I found a related post here: [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1475026) The solution is somewhat like this: wget -O /dev/null --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies=cookies.txt --post-data "ID=myID&password=myPassword&Submit=Submit" https://www.yourfavoritesite.com/login.asp i.e. to include 'submit' button. But on my page, the submit button does not have a name. So I am stuck again. p.s. Why can't I add your ID in front of my comments as you added my ID in front of your comments?

Comment: I think the lack of a name on your submit button is probably irrelevant - since the login form works in a browser, it can't be the case that it needs a name to work.  (You can't add my ID in your comments because you're responding to my answer, so your comments go to me automatically.)

Comment: Hi @RichieHindle, there could be an answer to this question. I am going to update my original post with the possible solution and my follow-up questions. Really appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: One more thing, it is required to use an ssh key to logon besides loginID/Password. I tend to guess this could block my wget attempt. But I don't know how to include the ssh key in my wget command.

Comment: @CharlieYen: It really looks as though this form does not want to be automated through wget.  :-(